# ArrayList as instance variable

Tags: java, arraylist, instance-variables

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student
{
    private String name;
    private int row;
    private int column;
    private ArrayList<Student> friends = new ArrayList<Student>;


    public Student(String newName, int newRow, int newColumn)
    {
        name = newName;
        row = newRow;
        column = newColumn;
    }

    public Student(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRow()
    {
        return row;
    }

    public int getColumn()
    {
        return column;
    }

    public void setRow(int newRow)
    {
        row = newRow;
    }

    public void setColumn(int newColumn)
    {
        column = newColumn;
    }

    public void addFriend(Student friend)
    {
        friends.add(friend);
    }

    public double getUnhappiness()
    {
        double unhappiness;
        unhappiness = Math.sqrt(((this.getRow() - friends.getRow()) * (this.getRow() - friends.getRow())) - 
                ((this.getColumn() - friends.getColumn()) * (this.getColumn() - friends.getColumn()))); 
        return unhappiness;   
    }
}
```

For the getUnhappiness method I am wondering how to access the row and column of the Students in the arraylist that I have as an instance variable. For example I am trying to get the row and column of the Student so that i can find the unhappiness

Comment: Hint- A list of students is not a Student.

Comment: But doesn't the list of Students contain Student objects which have the instance variables name,column, and row? In which case how would I access those?

Comment: Another hint : Look here to see how you can do that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550645/using-an-alternative-for-loop-syntax-to-get-objects-from-an-arraylist-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`friends.getRow()` and `friends.getColumn()` will give you error as those methods does not exist in an arraylist.

> I am wondering how to access the row and column of the Students in the arraylist

You have to specify the element in the arraylist, for example:

```
friends.get(0).getRow() //get row of friends' first element
friends.get(4).getRow() //get row of friends' fifth element
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is the syntax you have used to create the ArrayList is incorrect. It should be corrected as follows,

```
private ArrayList<Student> friends = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

or

```
private ArrayList<Student> friends = new ArrayList<>();//for java 1.7+
```

I am not clear what you mean by unhappiness, but you can come up with an answer as follows. Please explain what you really need to do, so I can give you a better answer.

```
 public double getUnhappiness() {
    double unhappiness=0;
    for (Student friend : friends) {//this will iterate over the friends
        double unhappinessWRT = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.getRow() - friend.getRow()), 2)
                - Math.pow((this.getColumn() - friend.getColumn()), 2));
        //here you get the unhapiness with respect to each friend
        unhappiness+=unhappinessWRT;//you can add unhappiness with each friend (or do what ever you need to do)
    }

    return unhappiness;
}
```